# Does using statement on SqlCommand.Connection behave the same?

Tags: c#, sql

Does placing a SqlCommand.Connection in a using block close the connection in the same way as placing the SqlConnection in it's own using block? (Is #1 = #2)

Example 1

```
using (var cmd = GetCommandWithConnectionSetInternally(connString))
{ 
    using (cmd.Connection) 
    {

    }
}
```

Example 2

```
using(var conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
     using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, conn))
     {

     }
 }
```

So, does the connection in Example 1 get closed as it would in Example 2 upon exiting the "using" block?

Comment: Not sure, but Example #1 just looks wrong to me.

Comment: You could, alternatively, omit the outer curly braces and stack the two using statements if you prefer that style.

Comment: I agree that #1 looks wrong, it just happens that we have a lot of legacy code that uses the #1 style. My DBA is complaining that there are a lot of "Sleeping" or "Awaiting Command" items when he runs sp_who2 on SQL. I don't even know if this is an issue, but I'm trying to figure out if the connections are being left open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't see it working any other way since using is just a short form of `try {} finally {}` with a `Dispose` call in the finally block. Since the resource object  being used is `cmd.Connection`, it should get disposed.

Comment: +1 - Plus, Example 2 is a more commonly accepted pattern for making DL logic.

Comment: @Tejs: Agreed, example 2 is much more readable and clear to me as well. I would avoid version 1.